# Como verificar a existência da classe nesse caso de jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Como posso verificar se a classe existe em uma **`variável`** da jQuery?

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // Captura o atributo para manipulá-lo
    var atributo = jQuery(this).parent('.servico').children('.servicos_the_content');
```

Tentei assim mas não deu certo:

```
if($(atributo)).hasClass('active'){

     // faz alguma coisa

}
```

Comment: Sua condição está errada, o `if` acaba aqui: `if($(atributo))`. Mude pra `if($(atributo).hasClass('active'))` e seja feliz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repara que tens um erro na lógica e parentesis:

```
if($(atributo)).hasClass('active'){
```

deve ser

```
if(atributo.hasClass('active')){
```

Neste caso `atributo` já é um objeto jQuery.